# Where to store javascript send grid api key safely?

Tags: javascript, email, firebase, angular, sendgrid

Where to store javascript send grid api key safely?

I have an angular2 app and want to store the api key in a safe place.
I'm using firebase and have no server side code like c#.

How is best to do this in angular js without someone loking through source files online to nick it.

**This is my current code:**

```
 sendGridTestEmail = () => {  
      //TODO - store this in safe place  
      var sendgrid_api_key = "";

      var sendgrid  = require('sendgrid')(sendgrid_api_key);

      sendgrid.send({
        to:       'test@gmail.com',
        from:     'support@gmail.com',
        subject:  'Hello Test',
        text:     'My first email through SendGrid.'
      }, function(err, json) {
        if (err) { return console.error(err); }
          console.log(json);
      });
  }
```

Comment: The SendGrid JS API is intended for use in Node.js on the server. There's no way to hide an API key if you're using the API directly from the browser.

Comment: I looked into zapier but could'nt get that working. Do you know any other alternatives?

Comment: Anything you do from the client is visible to the user. That's just the way it is.

Comment: Do you know any techniques where I can make it difficult for them to retrieve the api key? encryption? storing it in the Firebase database?

Comment: You can obfuscate the JS http://www.javascriptobfuscator.com/Default.aspx

Comment: But they can still see the AJAX parameters in Developer Tools.

Comment: You cannot see great answer to duplicate question here:
[Client-side coding: How to prevent malicious use?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/251707/client-side-coding-how-to-prevent-malicious-use#answer-251710)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is no way safely store any private key on the client.**

You can run a server though that sends emails and stores this API key. **[AppEngine is one of the easiest ways to run a server with Firebase.](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs)** The only supported Firebase client on AppEngine is Java client.

You can use the Firebase JVM Client with the SendGrid Java SDK, and run it on AppEngine.

[Here's a tutorial that takes you through the process. The tutorial does build an Android app, but you can use Android Studio for the Google Cloud tools.](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/firebase-app-engine-android-studio)

Comment: Hi David, would I need to know much about java to use this, as I'm a front end dev and have no java background?